# Cloudformation does not add `StackName` to the `State machine` name in Step Function

Tags: aws-cloudformation, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I noticed that if I don't add **StateMachineName** in Cloudformation template, then the name `State machines` is generated as follows:
[resource]-[uniqid]
but for all other resources in the template (Roles,LogGroup and etc), **StackName** is added to the name:
[stackname]-[resource]-[uniqid]

Why isn't StackName added to the name?
Is this a bug or is this how it should work?

I want the Cloudformation **StackName** to be automatically added to the **Step Function** for the **State machines** name:
[stackname]-[resource]-[uniqid]

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.

https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-resource-providers-stepfunctions/issues/44

This was discussed in a previous issue:
https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-resource-providers-stepfunctions/issues/26#issuecomment-1472949187